# How can we have two rows with same id in a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to make a GraphFrame made of vertices and edges dataframe. In the vertices dataframe, I see that I have same vertex twice, with same id and value. I am confused as I thought there should be a unique id for each vertex in the dataframe but it is not so as there are two rows with same ids. Can I get some explanation *why* are we allowed to have two vertices with same id in the dataframe and what consequences it can have in querying the dataframe and the Graphframe that uses it?
Note: I am using the vertex value as an id

```
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", "Alice"),
    ("a", "Alice"),
], ["id", "value"])
```

The output looks like

```
id   name
a    Alice
a    Alice
```

whereas I was expecting an error since the ids are same.

Comment: In pyspark dataframes the column value can be same(even in id column as in your case). If you need to generate a unique id u can use ROWNUMBER https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe `doesn't` throw any error when there are duplicated rows.

To eliminate duplicate rows you can use **`.dropDuplicates(),.distinct(),.row_number()..etc`** methods.

***Example:***

```
>>> v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
...     ("a", "Alice"),
...     ("a", "Alice"),
... ], ["id", "value"])
```

**`dropDuplicates():`**

```
>>> v.dropDuplicates().show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|Alice|
+---+-----+
```

**`distinct():`**

```
>>> v.distinct().show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|Alice|
+---+-----+
```

**`row_number():`**

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import *
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
>>> v.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("id","value").orderBy("id"))).filter("row_num =1").drop("row_num").show()
+---+-----+
| id|value|
+---+-----+
|  a|Alice|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not looking to delete duplicate rows. Please reread the question. I have asked about the reason for having duplicate ids in dataframes because ids are meant to be unique.